# angular.filter's groupBy filter : Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular, I need to use the angular.filter's `groupBy` filter but I am not sure how to include it. I followed the first 2 steps specified here: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby but can't follow the third step, i.e Add 'angular.filter' to your main module's list of dependencies.

This is the html file where I want to use it:

```
<div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">

    <thead>
        <tr align="center" style="outline: thin solid black">
            <th style="text-align: center">Review ID</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Reported Count</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Type of Review</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Link to review</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Expand/Collapse</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'ResourceId'">

        <tr>
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{value.length}}</td>
            <td>type goes here</td>
            <td>view</td>
            <td>expand</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Error: `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter`

JS file is as follows:

```
var admin = angular.module('admin', ['ngRoute']);
var delayTimer;

admin.config([
  '$routeProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
   function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/reported', {
        templateUrl: 'view/reported_reviews.html',
        controller: 'reportedController'
      })
   }
 ]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add angular-filter as a dependency and the reference

```
var admin = angular.module('admin', ['ngRoute','angular.filter']);
```

Reference

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.16/angular-filter.js" > </script>
```

Comment: I am getting these errors after following your answer [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module admin due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular.filter due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular.filter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Comment: Yes, Thankyou very much.